# Why are for each loops (as I understand them) unable to do things to arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have looked around for information regarding this kind of loop seen here:

```
listOfStrings = ["hey", "I", "am","still", "here"]
listOfStringsCopy = ["hey", "I", "am", "still", "here"]

for i in range(len(listOfStrings)):
    listOfStrings[i] = "something else"

for word in listOfStringsCopy:
    word = "something else"

print(listOfStrings, listOfStringsCopy)
```

which returns:

```
 ['something else', 'something else', 'something else', 'something else', 'something else']
 ['hey', 'I', 'am', 'still', 'here']
```

I have only begun to catch on now why this particular (*for word in*) loop seems to be wholly ineffective when you're trying to do anything to the list being looped. I think I recall reading somewhere that for each loops make a copy of the list or something, but have been unable to find anything concrete.

First, am I even referring to this kind of loop correctly? Is the second for loop I ran above a python "for each loop" even though the first loop above has incredibly similar syntax?

Second, can someone explain why this is and if I should stick to the regular first loop when I'm trying to do anything with a list besides key/dictionary processes?

**I have read the possible duplicate question and it kind of answers my question in that whenever I need to modify items in a list I need to loop indices, however I still want to know if there is any linguistic delineation between a loop that loops through indices and a loop that loops through elements of a list like in my second loop.**

Comment: It terms of python syntax there isn't a difference between a `for i in range...` and `for x in alist`. Both step through an iterable, a list or range. Also note the use of `enumerate` in some of the duplicate answers.

Comment: If you are replacing each element of a list, it might be faster and simpler to use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Second loop:

```
for word in listOfStringsCopy:
    word = "something else"
```

is not modifying the existing list because instead of modifying the list, you are actually re-binding the variable i.e. `word`, and this is obviously how we would want it to work.

This is equivalent to:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = x[0]
y = "something else"
```

Now, y does not refer to the first element of the list x, but it now refers to a string "something else".

Comment: `word = "something else"` does not create a new variable with the same name as the existing variable. It rebinds the existing variable. Rebinding that variable just doesn't do anything to the list.

Comment: thank you, this helps me understanding-wise a lot

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing that out, fixed the phrase.